# $\sqrt{x^{2}+\frac{1}{n}}$ converges uniformly to $\left|x\right|$

Tags: real-analysis

Im trying to prove that $f_{n}\left(x\right)=\sqrt{x^{2}+\frac{1}{n}}$  converges uniformly to $f(x) = \left|x\right|$ in $[-1,1]$.

So for evary $\varepsilon$ exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t for all $n>N$ and for all $x \in [-1,1]$   $\left|f_{n}\left(x\right)-f\left(x\right)\right| \le \varepsilon$

And this how i tried to continue :

$\left|f_{n}\left(x\right)-f\left(x\right)\right|=\left|\sqrt{x^{2}+\frac{1}{n}}-\left|x\right|\right|=\left|\sqrt{x^{2}+\frac{1}{n}}-\sqrt{x^{2}}\right|=\left|\frac{\left(\sqrt{x^{2}+\frac{1}{n}}-\sqrt{x^{2}}\right)\left(\sqrt{x^{2}+\frac{1}{n}}+\sqrt{x^{2}}\right)}{\sqrt{x^{2}+\frac{1}{n}}+\sqrt{x^{2}}}\right|=\left|\frac{x^{2}+\frac{1}{n}-x^{2}}{\sqrt{x^{2}+\frac{1}{n}}+\sqrt{x^{2}}}\right|=\left|\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\sqrt{x^{2}+\frac{1}{n}}+\sqrt{x^{2}}}\right|$

Which lead me to the same problem of $\left|\sqrt{x^{2}+\frac{1}{n}}-\sqrt{x^{2}}\right|$

any advice ?

Comment: $f_n$ is not defined on $[-\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}, \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}]$. Did you mean $+\tfrac{1}{n}$?

Comment: Thank you, yes that will be better. Well im trying to prove that a series of differentiable function that uniformly conveteg isnt necessarily differentiable . so I've created a function.I'll edit the question.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini's_theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a,b\ge 0,$ then $\sqrt {a+b} \le \sqrt a + \sqrt b.$ Proof: Square both sides. We conclude

$$\sqrt {x^2+1/n} \le \sqrt {x^2}+\sqrt {1/n},$$

which will lead to your result.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$\left\vert \sqrt{x^2 + \frac{1}{n}} + \sqrt{x^2}\right\vert \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}},$$
thus by your work thus far
$$\vert f_n(x) - \sqrt{x} \vert \leq \frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}.$$

Comment: Thank you, but why the first statment is correct ?

Answer (score 0):

You can notice that
$$
\sqrt{x^2+\frac1n}\le\sqrt{x^2+2\frac{|x|}{\sqrt n}+\frac1n}=\sqrt{\left(|x|+\frac1{\sqrt n}\right)^2}=|x|+\frac1{\sqrt n}.
$$
So $0<f_n(x)-|x|\le\dfrac1{\sqrt n}$. Hence, the uniform convergence (on all $\mathbb R$, not only on $[-1,1]$).